# E: Package 'python-minimal' has no installation candidate

Tags: package-management, python, lost-found

I am trying to deploy k8s cluster on aws using kubespray.

Step1: I have downloaded the following dependencies:

```
apt-get update  
apt-get install software-properties-common  
apt-add-repository ppa:ansible/ansible  
apt-get update  
apt-get install ansible  
apt-get update  
apt-get -y upgrade  
apt-get install python-pip  
pip install jinja2  
pip install netaddr
```

Step2: cloned the kubespray git repo

`git clone https://github.com/xenonstack/kubespray.git`

Step3: customized the inventory file, while deploying the cluster using ansible it is throwing the following error

`E: Package 'python-minimal' has no installation candidate`

How can i fix this?

Comment: last commit of OP's provided fork url: 6 years ago. Supported distributions: CoreOS (disappeared), Debian Jessie (ie: 8, we're at 12)., Ubuntu 16.04 (2016-2021?) . At least CentOS7 is still around. Maybe try https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray instead?

Answer (score 0):

You got the `E: Package 'python-minimal' has no installation candidate` message because the python-minimal package does not exist in your distribution's default repositories. The last Ubuntu distribution that had the python-minimal package in its repositories is Ubuntu 18.04 which is already End Of Life.

Install python2.7 instead.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python2.7
```

The python2.7 package has been discontinued in Ubuntu 23.04 and later. If you are using Ubuntu 23.04 either use python3 or else build python2.7 from source.

Results of `rmadison --url=debian python-minimal`:

```
python-minimal | 2.7.16-1      | oldoldstable | amd64, arm64, armel, armhf, i386, mips, mips64el, mipsel, ppc64el, s390x
```